# Safari - missing font weight component when retrieving font property from Canvas context

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-canvas

We are using Canvas Context object to convert the font size from `em/pt` in `px` like this:

```
<canvas id="test" style="width: 300; height: 100"></canvas>
...
<script>
var c = document.getElementById('test');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = 'bold 12px Arial';
var parsedFont = ctx.font;
ctx.fillText(parsedFont, 10, 60);
</script>
```

Output:

```
12px Arial
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1neqar7k/5/

The problem is, that in Safari, the `font-weight` component is lost. Am I doing something wrong or is this a Safari bug? Works fine in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed a bug, since [the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-context-2d-font) ask that,

> On getting, the font attribute must return the serialized form of the current font of the context (with no 'line-height' component).

And that the font weight should be part of the serialized form of the font, if not default (`400` or `normal`).

But note that even Chrome is buggy here, since they don't inlcude the font-weight property either if this one has been set by a numerical value:

```js
var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.font = '600 15px serif';
console.log(ctx.font); // only Firefox correctly outputs '600 15px serif'
```

---

But I don't see why you are using a CanvasRenderingContext2D to do this job...

CSS parsing and serializing is better implemented in the APIs that are first targets of CSSOM, e.g Element.
So if instead of using a canvas context you were using a dummy Element, then it would work everywhere as you wish:

```js
var el = document.createElement('foo');
el.style.font = '600 15px serif';
console.log(el.style.font);
```